# jQuery call with ajax not responding, no error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a small problem with a giftlist generated from SQL. My goal is to echo each row as a form with a textbox and a button, then when any button clicked, pass the textbox value, and an id number (hidden field value) to a function. Then this function would have get the values, and sends them with AJAX get method to a php, which would update a row with the giver's name in the SQL database. I cannot find the error in my code, so please help me in this regard.

*EDIT:* i need to figure out too, how to identify the button which was clicked.

This would be my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var aname = '';
        var tid = 0;
        $('.giftok').click(function()
        {
            if ($('.aname').val() === '')
            {
                alert('You have not provided your name.');
            }
            else
            {
                aname = $('.aname').val();
                tid = $('.id').val();

                $.ajax
                ({
                url: "kosarba.php",
                data: { ganame: aname, tid: gtid },
                type: "GET",
                context: document.body
                }).done(function() {
                    alert("OK, it works.");
                });

                alert('Thank you!');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my HTML+PHP:

```
echo "<table id='giftlist' align='center' font-size='10pt'>";
while($sor=mysql_fetch_array($sordb))
    {
        echo "<tr>
                <td width='420px'>$sor[gname]</td>
                <td width='65px'>$sor[gprice] Ft</td>";
        if (strlen($sor[aname]) !== 0)
            {
                echo "<td width='200px'>Sorry, someone already bought this one for us.</td>";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "<td width='335px'><form id='rendelget'>Your name: <input type='textbox' id='aname' name='aname' value='$aname'/><input type='hidden' class='id' name='id' value='$sor[id]'/>&nbsp;<button type='button' id='$sor[id]' class='giftok' value='Megveszem'>Megveszem</button></form> </td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: see your console log.

Comment: No error or warning.

Comment: Does the log show any activity?  Is the Ajax call making it to the server at all?  We need more to go on to be able to diagnose this.  Please post your console log for the ajax call to `kosarba.php`.

Comment: can you please open your network tab in inspect element? and check your request is successfully sent or not..

Comment: You can find some solution from there...

Comment: Is the click event fired?

Comment: Unfortunately the click is not fired at all. So it cannot reach the ajax call.

Comment: So wrap your code in document ready handler...

Comment: It seems i made it to work, but it always reads false data. ID is alwasy number 2, and aname do not get its value. Problem is how to identify that specific form which button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have mistaken a `variable` name `tid = $('.id').val()` `tid`
>   should be `gtid`

I think that would be your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aname = '';
    var tid = 0;
    $('.giftok').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).closest('form').attr('name') == 'myId'){ //or id
            if ($('.aname').val() === '')
            {
                alert('You have not provided your name.');
            }
            else
            {
                aname = $('.aname').val();
                gtid = $('.id').val();

                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "kosarba.php",
                    data: { ganame: aname, tid: gtid },
                    type: "GET",
                    context: document.body
                })
                .error(function(){
                    alert('Ajax worked but error form server.');
                })
                .done(function() {
                    alert("OK, it works.");
                });

               alert('Thank you!');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

//Update: If you identify the form holding the button gitve the form a name or id

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, it works! But somehow there is a need to identify which button was clicked.

Comment: Since i echo every row from a database, how can i assign different id to every form, and than how can i refer to a specific form at js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113804/discussion-between-prs-and-johnnygirl).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the ajax call,
data: { ganame: aname, tid: gtid }

'tid' is the post parameter, while gtid is the javascript variable.
Mistakenly, you have used **gtid** instead of tid .

use :
***data: { ganame: aname, tid: tid }***